# Change the API Version of the Azure Storage API

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I'm trying to deploy a function app which downloads a file from an azure storage account. Locally when I run the code it works fine with API Version 2020-10-02. However, when running the code from an Azure Function it does not work and raises the following error: `Result: Failure Exception: ValueError: Unsupported API version '2020-10-02'. Please select from: 2019-02-02 2019-07-07 2019-10-10 2019-12-12 2020-02-10 2020-04-08 2020-06-12`

I use the following code:

```
# Connect to CDE-Currated with the source list data
cdecurrated = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_str)
logging.info('Connected to CDE-Currated')

# Get the csv file based on the request and convert to xml
sl_file = cdecurrated.get_file_client(
    file_system='source-list', 
    file_path=f'{request["file_path"]}/{request["file_name"]}'
)
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(sl_file.download_file().readall()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the Azure SDK for Python - my colleague got it working by [manually specifying the `api-version`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/doc/dev/mgmt/multiapi.md#overview-of-a-multi-api-client) when creating the `DataLakeServiceClient` that had the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**As went thorugh the different [Storage Service API version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/previous-azure-storage-service-versions) only  `API version '2020-10-02'` as very less feature as comparsion to others. This Error you are getting for API version 2020-10-02 is not supported with Azure Function. This Might be reason you are getting an error.**

> Failure Exception: ValueError: Unsupported API version '2020-10-02'.
> Please select from: 2019-02-02 2019-07-07 2019-10-10 2019-12-12
> 2020-02-10 2020-04-08 2020-06-12.

Would Suggest you to please use the `API version` as recommanded in the Error or you can reach out to [***Azure Support***](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/) or Can raise a [***GitHub Issue***](https://github.com/features/issues) for root cause of this issue.

Comment: the problem seems to be caused by the Azure SDK for Python making an API call which is not supported. The link you give to github issues is not helpful, the correct link would be https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues